# Azure Logic App - BadRequest. Http request failed: the content was not a valid JSON

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have created a Logic APP in Azure which was working fine till now.  I am getting "BadRequest. Http request failed: the content was not a valid JSON" error from today.  Please note that no changes made to the SP.  Below is detailed process

1. Created SP in DB to generate the reports
2. Created Logic APP in Azure
3. Set the occurrence to run every week Monday at 1 AM

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Z9DC.png)

When i reran the report, facing the same issue again.  Then i connected to DB and manually ran the SP.  Then in Azure if i ran the report then it was success.  Really not sure how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Experienced the same issue, after this error is thrown if you go to the edit mode you will see a detailed error.

[image]

In my case, query results had the same column name when joining tables. Selecting specified columns in the sql query solved the issue.

Hope this would help!